# Jest: TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Tags: jquery, reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to test my Rails/React application by using `Jest`. I have a `Restaurant`component, and inside this component I call a modal through `$('.modal').modal();` in `ComponentDidUpdate`

Restaurant.js

```
class Restaurant extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      restaurant: [],
      dishes: [],
      current_user: '',
      favorite: false,
      loaded: false,
      commented: false,
    };
  }
  ....

  componentDidUpdate() {
    $('.modal').modal();
  }

  ....
}
```

And in my Jest test:

```
import Restaurant from '../app/javascript/components/Restaurant';

describe('<Restaurant />', () => {
  it("display restaurant's informations", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Restaurant restaurant={{ city: " paris  ", dishes_count: 73, full_address: "3 Rue Moret, 75011  paris", name: "Africa Délices", street: "3 Rue Moret", tags: ["Africain", "Halal"] }} />);
    wrapper.setState({ loaded: true });
    expect(wrapper.find('.restaurant-content li').text()).toEqual('Africa Délices')
  });
});
```

I have to `setState` the `loader` to display informations, but my test fail with the following message:

`TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function`

Modal come from Materialize.

I am starting to ask me if the issue is not because I use the Materialize modal which need `Jquery`, I guess it should a bad practice to use `Jquery` with `React`.

Nevertheless there is a way to avoid this error in my test ?

Thanks and let me know if you need more informations.

Comment: Are you sure the jquery you are importing/using comes packaged with the modal plugin?

Comment: When I run my server and I test in browser there is no issue, I have this error only during my automated testing. I am not importing Jquery in my test, thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you mock something like this and try ? you might also want to do force update on the wrapper before simulating the click.

```
window.$ = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
           return {
              modal: jest.fn()
            }
        });
```